# Included spring core, so why am I getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded" error?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Java 8 and Spring 5.  I have the following Grade dependencies for this Spring boot application I'm trying to build ...

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE'
}
```

After I build the application and run it, I get the below error ("java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded").  I'm including spring-core, so I'm not sure what it's complaining about ...

```
localhost:todoapp-backend davea$ java -jar ./build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar
12:37:24.249 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/mongodb-driver-3.4.1.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/bson-3.4.1.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/todoapp-backend/build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.9.jar!/]
12:37:24.255 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.bindSpringProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:530)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.bindSpringProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.handleProfileProperties(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:515)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:459)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:380)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:215)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:336)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.mkyong.Application.main(Application.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: I use mvn and having the same error for version 5.0.0, ErrorCoded is a deprecated class, I'm trying to figure out what is calling it.

Comment: My project is only spring not spring boot, and I also use mongodb. It used to be working just fine

Comment: Anyway I think it's only spring version conflict among projects. I'll make a coffee and spend a night on this now :D

Comment: Took one hour to figure out, but it's on track again :)

Comment: hi dave, anuy update on the issue? I have to update Spring in a old project, I get the same error and I don't see where the function ErrorCoded is called (in tests, it seems)

Answer (score 2):

Please don't mix Spring dependencies with Spring Boot dependencies on your gradle build file. For your project the dependencies should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.5.RELEASE'
}
```

I recommend using https://start.spring.io/ in order to generate a new Spring Boot project with all the dependencies you want.

Comment: I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext" now when I put in your dependencies and start things up.  Not sure if its related to what you have so I'm going to research a little more unless you have any knee-jerk reactions.

Comment: Even I  am getting error, this doesn't  answer this question

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem and solved, kept this page to help others :)

First of all believe me you have spring lib conflict issue.

[ErrorCoded class is Deprecated. 
as of Spring Framework 4.3.6](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE_to_4.3.11.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.11.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded.html)

This guy opened my eyes.

https://github.com/apache/dubbo-spring-boot-project/issues/219#issuecomment-403268651

I was depending spring core 5.0.5.RELEASE and mentioned ErrorCoded is deprecated after 4.3.6.

I use some other dependencies also depend older version of spring-core. That cause a conflict among projects for spring-core or related project.

```
spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE
spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.10.4.RELEASE
```

eclipse's pom editor shows dependecy hierarchy very well. 
if you have different version of spring-core, spring-beans ... components you can explicitly mention about the version you wanna use.

After finding conflicting project and its `spring-beans` misleading version, my problem is fixed.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Good luck!